# What is the Pali word for mundane knowledge ?

Tags: pali, knowledge, word

What is the Pali word for mundane knowledge

Comment: see also [pali word](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69221/pali-word) (chat)

Answer (score 3):

*Lokīya ñāṇa*, as opposed to *lokuttara ñāṇa* (supramundane knowledge)

Answer (score 2):

You should give use more reference, because there are many difference definition from each teacher.

However, I guess your question refer to objects, knowledge, of mundane right view in [mahācattārīsakasutta](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.117.than.html):

> “And what, bhikkhus, is right view? Right view, I say, is twofold: there is right view that is affected by taints, partaking of merit, ripening in the acquisitions; and there is right view that is noble, taintless, **supramundane**, a factor of the path.
>
> “And **what**, bhikkhus, **is right view that is affected by the taints, partaking of merit, ripening in the acquisitions?** ‘There is **what** is given and **what** is offered and **what** is sacrificed; there is **fruit** and **result** of good and bad actions; there is **this life** and the **next life**; there is **mother** and **father**; there are beings who are **reborn spontaneously**; there are in the **world good and virtuous recluses and brahmins** who have realised for themselves by direct knowledge and declare this world and the other world.’ This is right view affected by taints, partaking of merit, ripening in the acquisitions.

How to translate [this sutta-pāli](https://suttacentral.net/pi/mn117) by only pāli context without commentary and without own opinion:

> sāsavā puññabhāgiyā upadhivepakkā

- [saṅkhāra, kamma-bhava] right view that kilesa-vaṭṭa-paṭiccasamuppāda depending on [kāma-āsava (kāma-upādāna), diṭṭhi-āsava (diṭṭhi-upādāna, sīlabata-upādāna), bhava-āsava (attavāda-upādāna), avijjā-āsava],
- right view that is kammavaṭṭa-paṭiccasamuppāda,
- right view that give vipākavaṭṭa-paṭiccasamuppāda.

  1. atthi dinnaṃ [sukata­dukka­ṭā­naṃ kammānaṃ phalaṃ vipāko],

There is given-gift-action['s fruit and result of good and bad given-gift-actions].

2. atthi yiṭṭhaṃ [sukata­dukka­ṭā­naṃ kammānaṃ phalaṃ vipāko] ,

There is worshiped-action['s fruit and result of good and bad worshiped-actions].

3. atthi hutaṃ [sukata­dukka­ṭā­naṃ kammānaṃ phalaṃ vipāko],

There is given-oblation-action['s fruit and result of good and bad given-oblation-actions].

4. atthi **sukata­dukka­ṭā­naṃ kammānaṃ phalaṃ vipāko**,

There is fruit and result of good and bad actions.

5. atthi ayaṃ loko [sukata­dukka­ṭaṃ kammaṃ],

There is this-aggregate (=cause) [loka sutta].

6. atthi paro loko [phalaṃ vipāko],

There is another-aggregate (=effect).

7. atthi mātā [imā lokā sukata­dukka­ṭā kammāikā],

There are benefactor mother (=cause).

8. atthi pitā [imā lokā sukata­dukka­ṭā kammāikā],

There are benefactor father (=cause).

9. atthi [imā lokā sukata­dukka­ṭā] sattā opapātikā,

There are benefactor deva (such as died mother, died father).

10. atthi **loke** samaṇabrāhmaṇā **sammaggatā sammāpaṭipannā ye imañca lokaṃ
     parañca lokaṃ sayaṃ abhiññā sacchikatvā pavedenti.**

There are teachers who have done right path then have clearly viewed this-aggregate (=cause) and another-aggregate (=effect) by themselves.